# ConcourseCI --> Vagrant --> VM

Tags: vagrant

I have spent over 15 hours trying to get the concourse/lite box to come up with Vagrant.

I have tried VMWare Player x VirtualBox x 32-bit x 64-bit x CentOS x Ubuntu x RHEL x Windows x Vagrant 1.9.6 x Vagrant 1.9.7.

The closest I have come is to get Vagrant working on Windows, I can get a regular box to work, meaning vagrant up works and I can ssh into the machine.

However, when I run vagrant up with concourse/lite, with debug on, the output just keeps repeating itself - end result, nothing happens, the cycles just burn.

Can someone definitely explain whether the ConcourseCI vagrant box only works in special environments, special kernels, special blends, whatever the situation is, I just want to know what I am doing wrong here, because it should not be taking over 15 hours to run a simple vagrant up and keep failing over 10 different combinations of environments.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got it working using Docker.